# Exchange 2007 Send on Behalf of Permission

Tags: windows-server-2008, exchange-2007, outlook-2010

I am encountering a strange problem where a user has full access and send on behalf of permissions for a mailbox, but the permissions do not seem to be working as they should. When the user attempts to compose a new e-mail message using the address of said mailbox in the From field, they receive the following bounce back:

"Delivery has failed to these recipients or distribution lists:

Name (name@example.com)

You are not allowed to send this message because you are trying to send on behalf of another sender without permission to do so. Please verify that you are sending on behalf of the correct sender, or ask your system administrator to help you get the required permission."

As far as I can tell, I have set the required permission in the exchange management console (mail flow settings -> delivery options -> send on behalf of).

The user in question is using Outlook 2010 and our Exchange server is 2007. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way of doing this is: 
Open Exchange Console, navigate to Recepient Configuration, Mailbox. Right click on the user and "Manage send as permissions", give the permissions to the required user. What you're looking for is SEND AS and not SEND ON BEHALF.

Answer (score 1):

The "send on behalf of" properties on the mailbox is used for delegating rights to another user.  For example delegating an admin assistant rights to manage calendar items and send responses "on behalf of" the specified mailbox. This property would be added if you were to use Outlook to Delegate permissions.

As Vick pointed out in order to SEND AS another mailbox you will need to right click the user who you want to send as and select "Manage Send As Permissions..." and add the user there.

With Send on behalf of rights an email sent will come in as "on behalf of Joe Smith."

With Send AS rights an email sent will come in as "Joe Smith."

Comment: Just to confirm, you cannot compose new messages on behalf of someone?

Comment: No, you can compose a new message on behalf of someone. see: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/allow-someone-else-to-manage-your-mail-and-calendar-HA010075081.aspx

Comment: I didn't think so. Because the user has the send on behalf of permissions for the mailbox configured using the exchange management console, they should be able to put that mailbox name in the from field and have it appear as "user on behalf of mailbox name". I just don't understand why they keep getting the bounce-back saying they do not have the proper permission when it appears that they do.

Comment: When a delegate has Send on Behalf permissions, the delegate can compose an e-mail message and enter the manager's name in the From box. Recipients of the e-mail message will see the text Delegate Name on behalf of Manager Name next to From. -- Directly from the article.  To configure DELEGATE access you need to configure it using outlook, not the EMC as you have.

Comment: Strange...the users I have given the send on behalf of permission to are listed as delegates and have author permissions for all folders. Any other ideas? (appreciate all your help on this)

Comment: If the user is in cached mode, have them come out of cached mode and try sending on behalf of the mailbox in question.

Comment: Thanks. I will test this later this afternoon and let you know how it goes. Thank you again for your help.